# Creating a Quick Sort in VB

Tags: vb.net, quicksort, indexoutofrangeexception

I've recently started to learn VB and I've tried to create a quicksort. However when I run it, it returns an error and I'm unsure of where the error is in the code.

The error that it returns is this

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the
>   array.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Namespace Rextester
    Public Module Program
        Public Sub Main(args() As string)
            Dim quicksort() as Integer = {3,5,9,2,1,6,7}
            Dim counter as Integer

            Console.WriteLine(sort(quicksort, quicksort.length))
        End Sub

        Public Function sort(arr() as Integer, arrLen as Integer)as Integer()
            If arrLen <= 2 Then Return arr
            Dim more(arr.length) as Integer
            Dim less(arr.length) as Integer
            Dim i, l, m as Integer
            l = 0: m = 0
            Dim pivot as Integer = arr(0)

            For i = 1 to (arr.length-1)
                If arr(i) < arr(pivot)
                    Array.Resize(less, less.length+1)
                    less(l)=arr(i)
                    l = l + 1
                End If
                If arr(i) > arr(pivot)
                    more(m)=arr(i)
                    m = m + 1
                End If
           Next i 

           Dim moreVar = sort(more, m)
           Dim lessVar = sort(less, l)
        End Function   
    End Module
End Namespace
```

Comment: We don't have a vb compiler in school so we are having to use an online compiler that doesn't have the debugger. Therefore we cannot do it.

Comment: See if the instructor can get the class Visual Studio 2017 Community. It comes with compilers and debuggers and is free; although it might not be available in all areas of the world. Arrays in vb.net are zero based meaning the indexes of the elements start with zero. So if the length of the array is 5 then the indexes are 0,1,2,3,4 and would be declared array(4). 4 is the upper bound. Think about that and see if you can figure out where you have exceeded the bounds of your array.